# Mongoose removing double nested object with id's

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose structure:

```
{
    "_id": "5ea1a61c68b82c3a844e0a36",
    "decks": [
        {
            "cards": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ea1a61c68b82c3a844e0a38",
                    "countryname": "France",
                    "language": "French"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ea1a61c68b82c3a844e0a39",
                    "countryname": "Mexico",
                    "language": "Spanish"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5ea1a61c68b82c3a844e0a37",
            "name": "Countries"
        }
    ]
    "__v": 0
}
```

Lets say i want to delete the card france, how can i do this? ive looked at many examples but i cant seem to figure it out.
This is my mongoose query right now:

```
Decks.update({'_id': req.body.globalid},{$pull: {'decks.cards': {'_id': req.params.cardid}}}, function(err) {

    })
```

Thank you in advance

UPDATE!:

I got it eventually, solution:

```
Decks.update({"_id": req.body.globalid, "decks._id": req.params.deckid},{$pull: {"decks.$.cards": {"_id": req.params.cardid}}}, function(err) {

    })
```

Comment: Please post your update as answer, Or if you've find this somewhere in stack overflow you can mark your question as duplicate or delete it..